# Shutdown and make updates

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-prompt, shutdown

I have been trying to make a shutdown script which also runs updates on the computer. I have been trying with batch and with powershell but the shutdown cmd as I have understood it can't do this. I would appreciate it if anyone could give me some hints and tips!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/351937/how-do-i-force-windows-to-check-for-updates

Comment: The Windows Update API is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387287(v=vs.85).aspx) and you will do well to research Powershell scripts that contain `New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session`